# differences between how linux and windows performs date calculations

Tags: .net-core

Is there a major difference between how Linux and windows perform date calculations? I have an application at work that converts DateTime from whatever the local time zone is to UTC to be stored in the database. When I'm testing on my local windows dev machine it does this with no problem, however, in any higher environment (which is Linux) it appears to apply the time zone conversion twice. For Example, starting with a DateTime of "12/5/2022 08:00 AM" I'm in the Arizona time zone so UTC time is "12/05/2022 15:00" but instead of that value, I'm seeing a value of  "12/6/2022 02:00" being put in the database.  Has anyone run into this situation before? If so, how did you handle it?

```
            DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("The Current Datetime is: " +currentDate.ToString());

            currentDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(currentDate, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
            Console.WriteLine("Unspecified kind datetime is: " + currentDate.ToString());

            currentDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(currentDate, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
            Console.WriteLine("UTC time zone datetime is: " + currentDate.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Above are the pertinent date calculations I'm performing. I'm using .net core 3.1

Comment: There's no difference. If you care about timezones use DateTimeOffset, not DateTime. Right now you don't know *what* was stored, because the actual timezone offset was lost

Comment: `being put in the database.` using what code, into what type, what database product? Does the database column store local time perhaps? Or does it assume the input is local time stored into a UTC column?

Comment: We're using entity framework to put data into a MS Sql database. We have a table that contains our time zone information. Using that the example data is saved as using the Arizona time zone which has a -7 hour offset.

Comment: Are you sure the Linux server is at -7 instead of UTC? If it's a cloud VM it's most likely UTC. Why not use `datetimeoffset` and get rid of conversions?

Comment: I wouldn't mind using a datetimeoffset except this system is in production and even changing the two fields (StartDateTime and EndDateTime) for this one component would be a lot of work for something I can't guarantee would work.

Comment: Quite the opposite - with `datetimeoffset` you don't need to make *any* timezone change, so it doesn't matter what each machine's offset is. You actually see what the offset is all the time too. It's when you try to switch to local or UTC that information is lost and the potential for just such errors appear

Comment: In any case, no repro. The problem is in the database code and types. Please post code that actually reproduces the problem. The current code doesn't even convert between timezones, it only changes the DateTimeKind value

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce any problem nor did I expect to. There's no difference in date calculations between Windows and Linux. `being put in the database` that's probably where the problem is - trying to store *local* time in a database that has a different "local" offset from the server.

The question's code doesn't convert timezones either, it only changes the `DateTime.DateTimeKind` property. In all cases the DateTime value remains the same..

The call `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(currentDate, TimeZoneInfo.Local)` changes the `Unspecified` time to `Local`, not `UTC`. Even if the parameter was `TimeZoneInfo.Utc` though, it wouldn't matter because `Unspecified` has no offset to begin with.

The following program does convert and print to UTC.

```
var offset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow);
Console.WriteLine("{0} at {1}", Environment.OSVersion,offset);
Console.WriteLine();

DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime currentUtc=DateTime.UtcNow;

Console.WriteLine("The Current Datetime is: " +currentDate.ToString());
currentDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(currentDate, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
Console.WriteLine("Unspecified kind datetime is: " + currentDate.ToString());
currentDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(currentDate, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
Console.WriteLine("Not-UTC time zone datetime is: " + currentDate.ToString());

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Actual UTC datetime is: {0}", currentUtc);
Console.WriteLine("Current converted to  UTC datetime: {0}", currentDate.ToUniversalTime());

Console.ReadKey();
```

When run in Ubuntu, it prints the expected time:

```
Unix 5.15.74.2 at 02:00:00

The Current Datetime is: 12/06/2022 10:15:36
Unspecified kind datetime is: 12/06/2022 10:15:36
Not-UTC time zone datetime is: 12/06/2022 08:15:36

Actual UTC datetime is: 12/06/2022 08:15:36
Current converted to  UTC datetime: 12/06/2022 08:15:36
```

`DateTime.UtcNow` returns `08:15:36` instead of the local time, `10:15:36`. Converting `currentDate` to UTC with `ToUniversalTime` also converts the local time stored in `currentDate`.